# how to retrieve annotated and non-annotated methods present inside a perticular class

Tags: java, jsp, annotations

Using java reflection

```
class A {    
  @two    
  public method1()  {    
  }    

  @one    
  public method2()  {    
  }

  @two    
  public method3()  {    
  }

  public method4()  {    
  }      
 }
```

---

In the above given example of the code I want to retrieve annotated methods,non-annotated methods and all types of methods present inside a class as per the choice made by the user.
for example- In the example given above I want to retrieve only annotated methods of the class A or only non-annotated methods of the class A or all the methods present inside class A. What should be the code for this example.

can someone please help me out...

Comment: There are quite a few examples of searching for annotated methods take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593597/java-seek-a-method-with-specific-annotation-and-its-annotation-element or the following http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/FindAnnotatedMethod.htm

Comment: You should at least try something. The javadoc of Class and Method has all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Class clazz = B.class;

        List<Method> allMethods = new ArrayList<Method>(Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredMethods()));
        try {
            for (Method method : allMethods) {
                method.setAccessible(true);
                if (null != method.getAnnotations() && method.getAnnotations().length > 0) {
                    Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
                    System.out.println(method.getName());
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        System.out.println(annotation);
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println(method.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

public class B {

    public void getValue() {

    }

    @Deprecated
    public void getValue1() {

    }
}
```

**output**

```
getValue
getValue1
@java.lang.Deprecated()
```

Points to remember

1.) The above approach make use of `Java Reflection`.

2.) `java.lang.reflect.Method` has two methods `getAnnotations()` and `getDeclaredAnnotations()`, which can be used according to need. Please read Javadoc for details.

3.) It also has `isAnnotationPresent()` method which checks for specific annotation on a moethod.

4.) The abovecan be used to access field and method properties both.